# How can Iist only functions and those that come from a package

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

I use the `foreach` package to parallelize some stuff and I am tired of indicating 5 functions in `.export` everytime I need to use it.

I know I can do `foreach(...,.export=ls(.GlobalEnv))` but this transfers a lot of data to the workers and slow me down (there can be big tables defined).

So the question is how can I list only functions in the `.GlobalEnv`

I did that:

```
getAllFunctions <- function(envir=.GlobalEnv){
        allClasses <- sapply(grep(x=ls(envir), pattern='^%', value=TRUE, invert=TRUE), FUN=function(x){class(eval(parse(text=x)))})
        fnNames <- names(allClasses)[allClasses == 'function']
        return(fnNames)
}
```

But that's ugly (and gives everything) and I'm sure there is an idiomatic way

Comment: You could start with `ls.str(mode = "function", envir = .GlobalEnv)` I guess

Comment: or actually return thye functions with `as.list(.GlobalEnv)[sapply(.GlobalEnv, is.function)]`

Comment: @user20650: yes that nicer, I'll take that as an answer

Comment: or you could wrap davids answer in `mget`, which is a bit nicer / clearer i think

Comment: or possibly `Filter(is.function, as.list(.GlobalEnv))`

Comment: Suppose you want to include or remove those functions from certain packages you can go about that by filtering `search()`, e.g., `sapply(search()[1:3], ls.str)` will give you the first two attached packages, as well as the .GlobalEnv.

Comment: adding to Shayaa's comment. you can explicitly give the packages `mget(ls.str(paste0("package:", c("base", "stats")), mode="function"))`

Comment: In `foreach` package version 1.4.3, it is explained in the help for `foreach` function that `.export` is needed only for objects not in the current environment. It is also explained in the doc of the package page 9. So, in your case I think you do not have to export function to the worker if their already are in .Globalenv. `%dopar%` operator automatically to that for you. Leave the arg to NULL.

Comment: @Titolondon: I am using this version and I def. do have to export.

Comment: Strange. I noticed this automatic behaviour one day and since then I did not have to export objects for my current environement anymore. I just have to export the package I use for my code.

Comment: If it is not working for you a conclusion could be that it works for variable in .Globalenv but not functions... I will try next time to check that. 
one possibility is also to make a small package with the function you use for your project, and pass the package with `.packages`.

Comment: @Titolondon I agree to make a package out of my stuff, though it makes the dev combersome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

```
as.list(.GlobalEnv)[sapply(.GlobalEnv, is.function)]
```